# Spring mongo template projection of inner object field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

My object looks this way:

```
{
  "sourced": { "reference": "a", "otherField: 1 }
  "derived": "Q"
}
```

My final goal is to reduce it to:

```
{
  "reference": "a"
}
```

And remove all duplicates with distinct.

So far I got following working code:

```
@Data
private static class ReducedEntity {
    Sourced sourced;
}

@Data
private static class Sourced {
    private String reference;
}

var aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        match(new Criteria()),
        Aggregation.project("sourced")
        );
AggregationResults<ReducedEntity> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collectionName, ReducedEntity.class);
List<ReducedEntity> mappedResult = results.getMappedResults();
return mappedResult.stream().map(book -> book.sourced.reference).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It works but I prefer to have a single class with a reference property.

One interesting observation is that

```
Aggregation.project("sourced.reference")
```

will return null for `sourced`.

I tried to project "sourced.reference" to "reference" without luck. What's the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `Aggregation.project("sourced.reference")`, you no longer need the `ReducedEntity` class you directly use the `Sourced` class as outputType in the aggregate.

```
var aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.project("sourced.reference"));

AggregationResults<Sourced> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collectionName, Sourced.class);
return results.getMappedResults().stream().map(Sourced::getReference).collect(Collectors.toList());
```